# Thread mutual exclusion: mutex_lock implemented with mutex_trylock

Tags: c, gcc, locking, pthreads, mutex

In an OS project involving threads and processes in Linux I am trying to create a function Mutex_Lock in C similar to `pthread_mutex_lock` defined in `<pthread.h>` using a function called Mutex_TryLock similar to `pthread_mutex_trylock` defined in `<pthread.h>`. I was given this code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <pthread.h>
typedef volatile unsigned int Mutex;

int Mutex_TryLock(Mutex *lock)
{
    char oldval;
    __asm__ __volatile__("xchgb %b0,%1"
    :"=q" (oldval), "=m" (*lock)
    :"0" (0) : "memory");
    return oldval > 0;
}

void Mutex_Lock(Mutex* lock)
{
    while(! Mutex_TryLock(lock)) pthread_yield();
}
```

Mutex_TryLock was allegedly taken from Linux code. But if it works like `pthread_mutex_trylock` explained [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_mutex_lock.html) it should return zero on success and something non-zero on failure. So, on success in Mutex_Lock while loop condition will be true and the calling thread will be put on hold. On failure, while loop condition will be false and the calling thread will exit Mutex_Lock immediately. Isn't that the opposite of what `pthread_mutex_lock` should do? Or, Mutex_TryLock does not work like `pthread_mutex_trylock`?

Comment: Since you're already using `pthread_yield` (thus pthreads), why don't you use `pthread_mutex_lock`?

Comment: This is a restriction of the project. I mean I have to write code for some basic Linux threads' operations, but I can use the code I was given. In this case pthread_yield is considered given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Mutex_TryLock()` sets (part of) the lock to zero, and returns `true` if it was greater than zero before.  So less-than-or-equal to zero <=> locked, and greater-than zero <=> unlocked.  This much would be obvious if the "unlock" and the "init" functions were shown.

I'm not sure that declaring the mutex as an `unsigned int`, and then using only the first `char` of it (the `char` at the lowest address in the `unsigned int`), is entirely beautiful, particularly as your `char` may be signed !

Anyway, `true` returned from `Mutex_TryLock()` <=> lock was *unlocked* <=> lock acquired successfully.  So your `Mutex_Lock()` yields if the lock was not acquired successfully, which seems correct.

You are correct, `pthread_mutex_trylock()` returns `0` if the lock is acquired successfully, and an error return otherwise.  Amongst the possible errors is `EBUSY`, meaning that the lock could not be acquired because some thread alread has it locked.